# How to normalize data before calculating similarity distance between vector and matrix in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a user's taste table: `user_preference.head()`

```
genres  Action Adventure Animation Children Comedy Crime Documentary Drama Fantasy Film-Noir Horror IMAX Musical Mys...
userId                                                                      
18         0       0         0        0       1      0        0        0      0        0        0     0     0       0   
65         9       4         0        4      12      8        1       15      6        4        0     0     0       2   
96         0      16        16        0      16      0        0        0     16        0        0     0    16       0   
121        8       0         0        0      69      9        0       21      0        0        0     0     0       0   
129       11      14         0        3      85      4        4       46      3        0        2     3     0      19
```

And I have movie's genre content table:

```
genres  Action Adventure Animation Children Comedy Crime Documentary Drama Fantasy Film-Noir Horror IMAX Musical Mys...
movieId                                                                     
10         0       0         0        0       1      0        0        0      0        0        0     0     0       0   
11         0       0         0        0       1      1        0        1      0        1        0     0     0       0   
12         0       1         0        0       1      0        0        0      0        0        0     0     0       0   
13         0       0         0        0       0      0        0        1      0        0        0     0     0       0   
14         0       1         0        0       0      1        1        0      0        0        0     0     0       1
```

I am trying to take each user's preference vector and get it's similarity measure with movie's content in order to recommend most preferential movies by taking dot product:

```
distances = np.dot(movie_content_df, user_preference[1].reshape(-1, 1))
```

To calculate the distance I first normalized the user's preference table by:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

user_preference_tmp = user_preference.copy()
norm = MinMaxScaler().fit(user_preference_tmp)
user_preference_norm = norm.transform(user_preference_tmp)

print(user_preference[1])
print(user_preference_norm[1])
________________________________________________________________________
([ 0,  9,  4,  0,  4, 12,  8,  1, 15,  6,  4,  0,  0,  0,  2,  7,  7,  10,  0,  0])
[0. 0.00239107 0.00131709 0. 0.00355872 0.00212352 0.00300639 0.00044287 0.001469 0.00358637 0.01520913 0. 0. 0. 0.00174978 0.00237691 0.0026616 0.00241604 0. 0. ]
```

I don't understand why after normalization `user_preference_norm[1]` represents different preferences? For example third and fifth values are both `4` but after normalizing I got `0.00131709` and `0.00355872`, or the biggest value `15` transforms into `0.001469`, which after dot product gives less similarity value.

Is it right to normalize the data before computing dot product? If it is am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the right output, which represents the right user's preferences:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
user_preference_tmp = user_preference.copy()

norm = Normalizer().fit(user_preference_tmp)
user_preference_norm = norm.transform(user_preference_tmp)

print(list(user_preference[1]))
print(user_preference_norm[1])
_______________________________________________________________________________
[0, 9, 4, 0, 4, 12, 8, 1, 15, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 7, 7, 10, 0, 0]
[0.         0.31799936 0.14133305 0.         0.14133305 0.42399915
 0.2826661  0.03533326 0.52999894 0.21199958 0.14133305 0.
 0.         0.         0.07066653 0.24733284 0.24733284 0.35333263
 0.         0.        ]
```